# How can I get data from server located .txt file or .php file

Tags: c#

What i want is :

For ex :

mysite.com/test.txt

```
123818
195394
590102
569838
..
..
```

mysite.com/simple.php

```
<?php echo "Sample thing etc." ?>
```

How can i fetch that kind of datas in easy way, i'm beginner sorry for easy question

Thanks for help

Comment: look into file handling functions, should be a piece of cake after you have a hang of them

Comment: Any example tutorial which have easy expression

Comment: @1342 please change tags. If you are using php, add php tag...

Comment: i have no problem with php page, it'll make easy html output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would just like to download some data from the server, you can use something like this:

```
var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
string data = client.DownloadString("http://mysite.com/test.txt");
```